# Many transaction commit redelivered(true) log entries

Tags: oracle, jms, apache-camel, tibco, xa

I have a Camel app setting up a route from JMS (Tibco) queue writing to a DB (Oracle) in an XA transaction (using Atomikos).
On larger messages, we see a lot of "transaction commit redelivered(true) on messageId xxx".

Why would there be so many "redelivered(true)" messages?

I asssume it takes too long to write larger > 1 MB messages to the DB - is there a way of increasing the timeout - so that a transaction can take more time on both the Tibco and Oracle side? I have already set the jta timeout to a larger value for Atomikos in jta.properties - but still immediately after starting the app some messages are processed but many redilvered notices keep on being written.

Thanks
Thomas

Comment: Your best start is to see if you can track such a transaction in the logs and possible see if there is a pattern. Try to recreate the issue in a test/debug environment - turn on appropriate debug logging and see if you can clock the transaction at various points. It could be a lot of things playing in. JTA timeouts, flow timeout, various other errors etc. Also consult the Atomikos log - it's usually fairly expressive if you can find the correct entires for a failing transaction. JTA is truly awesome. Unit you hit performance limits - or have to troubleshoot. I wish you a good hunt!